# QSqlDriver::close crashes application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've a weird problems with QSqlDriver and QSqlDatabase.

In my program I open a database connection. When main window is being closed and all objects are being destroyed, an object which holds QSqlDatabase tries to call close() on it. It causes a crash.

My investigation shows that: QSqlDatabase invokes close() on driver. However for some reasons, a pointer to proper close() function in vtable of driver (QSqlDriver) points to invalid memory area (not allocated).

Valgrind says the same - a usage of not allocated (and not recently freed memory).

What I've also discovered, is that this invalid pointer points to area where libqsqlmysql library was originaly loaded. However when application closes, library is being unload (too soon for me).

My question: is this behaviour (unload of sql plugins of QSqlDatabase) somehow described? When does it exactly occur? I could not find any specifications.
Other question is that if this is a normal behaviour or I did something wrong?

**EDIT**

I've filled a bug report for this issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in my specific case was that I was holding the connection to the Database (QSqlDatabase) in a class. I shouldn't have done this, but used the static methods to get the singleton.

In my Constructor:

```
Database::Database() {
   QSqlDatabase conn = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", dbName);
   conn.setDatabaseName(dbName);
   if (!conn.open())
   {
       qDebug() << conn.lastError().text();

       QMessageBox msgBox;
       msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
       msgBox.setText(conn.lastError().text());
       msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
       msgBox.exec();
       QApplication::quit();
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to access the connection

```
QSqlDatabase conn = QSqlDatabase::database(dbName);
QSqlQuery statement(conn);
```

This stopped the crashes on exit for me

[Source](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15493-Releasing-database-file-with-QSqlDatabase/page2)

Comment: Note that if you have open queries & call this method the conn.open() will reset the connection(which is bad news for the open queries). Its better to use if (!conn.isOpen()) then call .open() only once when needed.
(Also In case of persistent/idle db connections timing out, you can keep the connection alive by querying SELECT 1 periodically)